# Does an entertaining guide exist?

Tags: python

I know of the few normally mentioned Python tutorial/guides/introductions, but I was wondering if there were any that were...more entertaining to go through, I guess.

For example, Ruby has [Why's (Poignant) Guide to Ruby](http://mislav.uniqpath.com/poignant-guide/), Haskell has [Learn You a Haskell for Great Good](http://learnyouahaskell.com/), PHP even has [this](http://devzone.zend.com/article/627) set of tutorials. Is there a Python equivelant?

Comment: -1: "entertaining" is subjective.  Please mark the question with the subjective tag.  I find facts entertaining.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

[A Byte of Python](http://www.swaroopch.com/notes/Python)

For real entertainment, take [The Python Challenge](http://www.pythonchallenge.com/).

Comment: Looks decent, thanks. 

I actually messed around with The Python Challenge, but...I got to the first actual level and couldn't figure it out. :-p.

Answer (score 1):

Not a guide exactly but this is a game for python coders. check it out it
http://www.checkio.org/

Answer (score 0):

I'm partial to [Dive Into Python](http://www.diveintopython.net/), myself.  Now [updated for Python 3](http://diveintopython3.net/), too.

Not as silly as *why's (Poignant) Guide to Ruby*, but that's a plus, in my opinion.  *Dive into Python* strikes a nice tone.  It's interesting without wasting too much of your time.